# How to trace OSUSER in oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I've created a stored procedure few days back. But someone had removed all the changes I've made. Is it possible track the **OSUSER** who performed ddl changes on sproc.

- Using **DBA_Objects** table I tracked that some ddl change had been performed.

But unable to get the OSUSER. The sql developer is hosted in citrix. So logged in username is same for everyone. But **OSUSER** will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly saying this kind of granular details is very very difficult to get. You can get the lastddl time from dba_objects. 
May I know why this kind of granular details is required?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your best bet is to check DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL. In [Oracle AUDIT documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4007.htm) you can see at the end in last example if

```
AUDIT ALTER, GRANT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
    ON DEFAULT;
```

was executed then this should apply

> If you create a procedure, package, or function, then Oracle Database
>   automatically audits any ALTER or GRANT statements issued against it.

So if ALTER PROCEDURE was used I guess it should be in there. I'm not so sure if CREATE OR REPLACE is audited this way.

Comment: Thanks for the details.. As per the link you've shared, the statement written specifies default auditing options for objects created in the future. But the execution had already been done. For future I can use the statement. But, currently how can I trace the osuser?

Comment: Yes maybe I wasn't clear in my answer but that's exactly how I meant it. It's always worth checking maybe your DBA or somebody enabled this auditing. If not well I suggest you to enabled it to prevent these problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You also can create trigger to audit ddl on your schema, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SYS.{your_schema}_DDL_TRIGGER
before ddl on {your_schema}.schema
declare
   i number;
begin
   sys.dbms_system.ksdwrt(2, to_char(sysdate,'YYYY.MM.DD hh24:mi:ss') || ' Detected DDL on schema TBG from' ||
                         ' ip_address ' || sys_context('userenv', 'ip_address')||
                         ' Username ' || sys_context('USERENV','SESSION_USER')||
                         ' OSUser ' || sys_context('USERENV','OS_USER') ||
                         ' Module "' || sys_context('USERENV','MODULE') ||
                         '" ora_sysevent ' || ora_sysevent ||
                         ' ora_dict_obj_name ' || ora_dict_obj_name ||
                         ' ora_dict_obj_type ' || ora_dict_obj_type ||
                         ' ora_dict_obj_owner ' || ora_dict_obj_owner );
exception when others then
   null;
end {your_schema}_ddl_trigger;
```

Comment: Good idea; just a warning that using an undocumented package function such as `sys.dbms_system.ksdwrt` would not be a good idea...